# Mikro ORM + MongoDB + GraphQL Querying Error With Embedded Objets/Arrays

Tags: mongodb, orm, graphql, mikro-orm

this may get a little long but there are a lot of weird issues to explain.

The error message I receive when running queries is:

```
"stacktrace": [
        "SyntaxError: Arg string terminates parameters early",
        "    at new Function (<anonymous>)",
        "    at Function.createFunction (/Users/zacktidwell/repos/services/graphql/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/utils/Utils.js:611:52)",
        "    at ObjectHydrator.getEntityHydrator (/Users/zacktidwell/repos/services/graphql/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/hydration/ObjectHydrator.js:221:40)",
        "    at ObjectHydrator.hydrate (/Users/zacktidwell/repos/services/graphql/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/hydration/ObjectHydrator.js:23:30)",
        "    at EntityFactory.hydrate (/Users/zacktidwell/repos/services/graphql/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/entity/EntityFactory.js:82:27)",
        "    at EntityFactory.create (/Users/zacktidwell/repos/services/graphql/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/entity/EntityFactory.js:36:14)",
        "    at MongoEntityManager.find (/Users/zacktidwell/repos/services/graphql/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/EntityManager.js:100:52)",
        "    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)",
        "    at async EntityLoader.populateMany (/Users/zacktidwell/repos/services/graphql/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/entity/EntityLoader.js:127:22)",
        "    at async EntityLoader.populateField (/Users/zacktidwell/repos/services/graphql/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/entity/EntityLoader.js:187:9)",
        "    at async EntityLoader.populate (/Users/zacktidwell/repos/services/graphql/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/entity/EntityLoader.js:37:13)",
        "    at async MongoEntityManager.lockAndPopulate (/Users/zacktidwell/repos/services/graphql/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/EntityManager.js:630:9)",
        "    at async MongoEntityManager.findOne (/Users/zacktidwell/repos/services/graphql/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/EntityManager.js:244:9)",
        "    at async queryName
      ]
```

I am 95% sure this error is caused by the Embedded objects I have set up.
Here's an example of an entity:

```
    export class Properties extends BaseEntity {
        @Embedded({ entity: () => Address, object: true })
        address = new Address();
    
        @Property()
        market: string;
  
        @Embedded({
          entity: () => Metadata,
          array: true,
          object: true,
          nullable: true,
         })
         details: Metadata[] = [];

        @Embedded({
          entity: () => Metadata,
          array: true,
          object: true,
          nullable: true,
         })
         features: Metadata[] = [];

         constructor({address, market }) {
           super();
           this.address = address;
           this.market = market;
         }
      }
```

And the Embeddable for the array:

```
@Embeddable()
export class Metadata {
  @Property()
  id?: string;

  @Property()
  metaKey?: string;

  @Property()
  metaValue?: string;

  @Property()
  createdAt?: string;
}
```

The weird things that I'm racking my brain over:

- This error is inconsistent, some times it happens on the first
  relationship I query, some times the third, even if it's the exact same
  query.
- This happens most commonly on relationships. If it's the main entity in a query,
  the error rarely occurs. I can query an entity and it will work fine, but if I
  query a different entity with that original one as a relationship, it will not.
- It seems to break other queries. I can run a query and it will work, then run a
  different query and it won't. Doing it in reverse, the same thing happens, the
  first query works, and the second doesn't.
- Removing some of the embeddables will "fix it", but it doesn't matter which
  embeddables. It seems to be more of an amount of embedded objects that break it,
  not necessarily any particular ones. (I have ten different embeddables,
  and an entity will have up to eight embedded embeddables and up to five of the
  same embeddable with for a different field)
- I've tried various different ways to write or initialize the embedded objects:

  ```
     @Embedded({
        entity: () => Metadata,
         array: true,
         object: true,
         nullable: true,
        })
        details = new Metadata();

      @Embedded({
        entity: () => Metadata,
         array: true,
         object: true,
         nullable: true,
        })
        details?: Metadata;

      @Embedded({
        entity: () => Metadata)
        details?: Metadata[];

     // and various combinations of {array: true} and {object: true}
  ```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Maybe you are using some outdated version? https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/1585

Comment: I thought that as well, but updated it earlier today and still running into the same issues. Sorry, I should have included that.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone running into this issue, it was actually a problem on Mikro ORM's side. A regex typo was preventing an entity from having more than 10 embeddables. It has since been fixed; so update your package if you're having this problem.